# How can I export biar file from BO4 to BO3?

Tags: business-objects

I want to make a biar file from BO4 and import to BO3. I use upgrade management tool to export biar from BO4.I successfully created biar but when I import biar file to BO3 with importwizard tool I got this error :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a supported functionality as there is a major changes in architecture of 4.0

Answer (score 2):

BIAR files are not downward compatible across major versions.